# how to concat year and month in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to concat `year` and `month` in eloquent

```
id   month  year
1     5     2021
2     5     2020
3     6     2021
4     12    2020
5     11    2021
```

How can I return the response like

```
id  concatenated_date
1       202105
2       202005
3       202106
4       202012
5       202111
```

**EDIT**

I want to use this concat part in my repository in which I'm using eloquent

```
use App\Models\SampleTable;

public function fetchData($month, $year, $with=[]) {
     $sampleTable = SampleTable::$TABLE_NAME;
     
     $model = SampleTable::with($with)
               ->where($sampleTable.concatenated_date, XYZ);
     return $model->selectRaw($sampleTable.value);
}
```

My table consists of

```
 id   concatenated_date   value
 1     202105              10
 2     202004              20
 3     202011              30
```

In the place of `XYZ`, how should I write the concat of month and year?

Comment: do you want to concatenate in the code ? or maybe at view level ? or at the database level to include in another query ?

Comment: At the DB level. Apologies for not mentioning that.

Comment: Maybe add the use you're planning for it to your question, so we can help you more efficiently.

Comment: @N69S, can you check now?

Comment: So you want to concatenate the `year` and `month` to use it in a `where` clause?

Comment: @Peppermintology, Correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're mentioning eloquent, I expect you to have a model so you can use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```php
class SampleTable extends Model
{
    public function getConcatenatedDateAttribute()
    {
        return $this->year.str_pad($this->month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
}
```

You can then use `$model->concatenated_date`.

Comment: @Peppermintology.good catch .i was expecting to do that change

Comment: Does this work when I need `202006` if the value of month is 6 and year is 2020?

Comment: Now, it does :D I added that to the answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this at the database level, you might be best using a `raw` query:

```php
$models = Model::select('*', DB::raw('CONCAT(year, LPAD(month,2,0) AS concatendated_date')
                 ->get();
```

Obviously you'll want to replace `Model` with your actual `Model` name and other operations can be added (`where` etc.).

**Update**

Based on recent comments/updates that you want to use the concatenated date as part of a query, the [answer from @shaedrich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68005454/281278) covers how you would concatenate the `year` and `month`.

```php
use App\Models\SampleTable;

public function fetchData($month, $year, $with=[]) {
    $sampleTable = SampleTable::$TABLE_NAME;
     
    $concatenated_date = $year.str_pad($month, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);

    $model = SampleTable::with($with)
               ->where($sampleTable.$concatenated_date , XYZ);
     return $model->selectRaw($sampleTable.value);
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with Eloquent query?

Comment: @astroboy1 it is using eloquent. To get better help, upgrade your question, add more details on what you want to achieve with this concatenation.

Comment: @astroboy1 You'll need to update your question to include `exactly` what it is you want for us to help you further.

Comment: @Peppermintology I've edited, can you check now?